# How to generate JSON in Java with clean code

Tags: java, json, spring, performance, coding-style

I have code like this:

```
Map<String, Object> tempParam = new HashMap<>();
tempParam.put("custid", "123");
json = gson.toJson(tempParam);

String keyParams = "schema;tablename;where;clause";
String valueParams = "dbtrial;mastercustomer;"+json+";sort=id,date_&limit=10";

String res = genJSON(keyParams, valueParams);

function genJSON(String keyParams, String valueParams){

    String[] key = keyParams.split(";");
    String[] value = valueParams.split(";");

    JSONObject objectMessage = new JSONObject();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < key.length ; i++){
        objectMessage.put(key[i], value[i]);
    }

    return objectMessage.toString();
    
}
```

My concern is the way of writing with semicolon separators, then split,
Is there another way that is simpler or more effective ? can we make it more dynamicly ?
because the "genJSON" function will be used globally for various needs.
at least I want clean code.

I've tried using arrays like this, but it doesn't seem to make much of a difference.

```
String[] keyParams = ["schema", "tablename", "where", "clause"];
String[] valueParams = {"dbtrial", "mastercustomer", json, "sort=id,date_&limit=10"};

function genJSON(String[] keyParams, String[] valueParams){

    JSONObject objectMessage = new JSONObject();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < keyParams.length ; i++){
        objectMessage.put(keyParams[i], valueParams[i]);
    }

    return objectMessage.toString();
}
```

Do you have any other thoughts or suggestions that might be better?

*I used java 7*

Comment: Why not use a map like you are using to generate the `json` object using `gson`?

Comment: First of all, this is not even valid Java code. You don’t see a difference between these variants as the surrounding code, most likely code sending requests over the network dominates the execution time. Even if you look at the string generation in isolation, the work hidden beneath the `JSONObject` outweighs your processing of the eight strings. If seven of these strings are constants, why don’t write the JSON string in the first place, `String result = """ { "schema": "dbtrial", "tablename" : "mastercustomer", "where" : """ + json + """, "clause": "sort=id,date_&limit=10" } """;`

Answer (score -1):

Your attempt to use arrays for `keyParams` and `valueParams` is a good idea to make the code cleaner and more maintainable. However, there's a minor issue with the way you're initializing arrays in Java. Here's the corrected code:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JSONObject tempParam = new JSONObject();
        tempParam.put("custid", "123");
        String json = tempParam.toString();

        String[] keyParams = {"schema", "tablename", "where", "clause"};
        String[] valueParams = {"dbtrial", "mastercustomer", json, "sort=id,date_&limit=10"};

        String res = genJSON(keyParams, valueParams);
        System.out.println(res);
    }

    public static String genJSON(String[] keyParams, String[] valueParams) {
        JSONObject objectMessage = new JSONObject();
        for (int i = 0; i < keyParams.length; i++) {
            objectMessage.put(keyParams[i], valueParams[i]);
        }

        return objectMessage.toString();
    }
}
```

This code will work as expected, and it's a cleaner way to manage your `keyParams` and `valueParams`. The main advantage of using arrays is that it allows for better organization and readability of your code, especially if the number of parameters grows.